# call HTTP POST android

Tags: android

Hello this is my code in my android app to verify the login. This works fine but now i want to call a http POST method in my PHP file so that i can call more than one method. How can i do that.

```
void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://www.c-    iris.com/v2/app/webService.php"); 
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
                }
            });
            //startActivity(new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, UserPage.class));

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my PHP file:

```
 <?php
include ('../inc_php/databaseConnectie.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$accountsQuery = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE email = '".$username."' AND wachtwoord =     '".md5($password)."'";
if ($accountsResult = $mysqli->query($accountsQuery)) 
{   
if ($accountsResult->num_rows >= 1)     
{
    echo "User Found"; 
}
else
{
    echo "No Such User Found";
}
}
?>
```

For example:

```
enter code here

if($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'login')
{
//than execute the code above.......
}
```

but how can i call this method from android?

Comment: m bit unclear with ur question ...but whenever u fire ur question php function will be called ..just pass string param which says ur module is login instead of checking methof

Comment: This is not possible, have a look at restful apis, this is http://www.restapitutorial.com/ a good point to start!

Answer (score 0):

Just comment  below line

```
 //Execute HTTP Post Request
  response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In log in method you send data twice with different objects so just remove above line in method.